# Error using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-management-api

In my Azure Function, I've referenced `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites` assembly

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites": "4.0.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

and trying to use `WebSiteManagementClient`:

```
var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(
    new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CertificateCloudCredentials("my sub ID", cert));
```

But it fails with an error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common: 
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.ServiceClient`1'
threw an exception. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common: Operation is not 
supported on this platform.
```

In the log I can see

```
Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.NetFramework'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.WindowsStore'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.WindowsPhone'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.WindowsPhone81'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Silverlight'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Test'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
```

I tried to reference all dependent NuGet packages too, but with no luck to fix the error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Adding below items fixed the issue.

```
 //Add in run.csx
 using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites;
```

Add below JSON config in project.json

```
    {
      "frameworks": {
        "net46":{
         "dependencies": {
         "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites": "4.0.0",
         "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common": "1.4.1"
         }
        }
       }
      }
```

For Additional information: 
I have also tried with latest pre-release version,

```
    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites": "5.0.0-prerelease"
```

Azure Functions worked well with the pre-release too.

Comment: Not for me... Tried it before, and now tried it again by copy-pasting your json. Still same error.

Comment: Lools like issue is not due to var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(
    new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CertificateCloudCredentials("my sub ID", cert));   Please examine your project lock json under view files in Azure Functions and check whether all necessary packages have been included.